# JSON response in correct format

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm querying a table called 'users' in my database via PHP.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, lastname FROM $tableName");         

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            echo json_encode( $row );
        }
    }
    else 
    { 
        echo json_encode( "No rows found!" );
    }
```

I get this table back in a JSON response as follows..

```
["John","Smith"]["John","Wayne"]
```

However my desired format is as follows.

```
{ "users" : [
  {
    "name":"John",
    "lastname":"Smith",
  },
  {
    "name":"John",
    "lastname":"Wayne",
  }
]}
```

Is there a way to query the data and have it returned along with the table name like the format above??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in place of your current code:

```
<?php
$userInfo = array("users" => array());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, lastname FROM $tableName");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $userInfo["users"][] = array("name" => $row[0], "lastname" => $row[1]);
    }
    echo json_encode($userInfo);
}
else 
{ 
    echo json_encode( "No rows found!" );
}
```

**EDIT**

I just saw that you want this to be a somewhat dynamic result fetch using the table and column names, if you want this to be done as such you should use the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` rather than `mysqli_fetch_row()` like this:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name, lastname FROM $tableName");
$tableData = array($tableName => array());

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tableData[$tableName][] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($tableData);
}
else 
{ 
    echo json_encode( "No rows found!" );
}
```

Comment: Also I'd like to note that the `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated and are no longer supported, please start writing new code using the `mysqli_*` functions.

Comment: Thank you @iamde_coder. Sorry only getting back into PHP again for the first time in a long time. Thank you for your help and advice.

Answer (score 1):

What if you do this. Put the rows into an array and encode that.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, lastname FROM $tableName");         

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
        $users = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            $users['users'][] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode( $users );

    }
    else 
    { 
        echo json_encode( "No rows found!" );
    }
```

Comment: you would also have to add code for the name and lastname fields.